# What are the initial lines in wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have some lines at the beginning of my wpa_supplicant of my android phone. The file starts like this:

```
ctrl_interface=wlan0
update_config=1
device_type=0-00000000-0

network={
..
```

I have the following questions:

1. What are those initial 3 lines at the beginning of the file?
2. Are those lines necessary and are these lines different for each device?
3. Are there are *always* 3 lines or more lines could be present?

I am asking this because I want to write a shell script to connect to try out a bunch of wpa_supplicant files. So I want to know if having these lines would be necessary in each of my configuration file?

**Edit:**

My `wpa supplicant -v` command shows:

```
wpa_supplicant v0.8.x 
Copyright (c) 2003-2011, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

Comment: Android phones are off topic here. The problem is that while wpa-supplicant is a standard linux tool is is highly possible that is has been customised and would therefore be out of scope for this site. It's difficult for us to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctrl_interface` is the interface (adapter) that is being used to connect to the WiFi.

`update_config` does not seem to be a feature of `wpa_supplicant`. I have no idea why it is there.

`device_type` same as the above. No idea why it is there.

My `wpa_supplicant` files don't have the second and third of those lines in them.

Comment: Any idea where I could find more info about it?

Comment: @PervySage Hmmmm....Could be that Android uses its own version of `wpa_supplicant`. Can you run `wpa_supplicant -v` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Not so sure about that but added the info to the question. PLease see the edit.

Comment: @PervySage Strange...my `wpa_supplicant` reports version 2.0. Yours must be quite outdated. I'll see if I can find documents for your version.

Comment: @PervySage I found the docs for `wpa_supplicant v0.8.x`, and they also do not mention `update_config` or `device_type`.

Comment: That's strange. :-/
My phone is quite old and it had CyanogenMod (CM9). But really thanks for the time and effort! :-)

I can't upvote, though. It requires a rep of 15. :-(

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where can I find the docs of various verions?

Comment: @PervySage Ha. That wasn't easy. I got them from [here](http://download.tizen.org/releases/daily/2.0alpha/common/latest/repos/tizen-main/source/wpa_supplicant-0.8.0-slp.9.2.src.rpm) (seems to be down right now, it wasn't earlier today). The official website is [here](http://w1.fi).